# Connect to azure cluster in octopus

Tags: azure, kubernetes, octopus-deploy

I am trying to deploy a yaml file to an existing azure kubernetes cluster via octopus,

The command I use is inside a powershell script that runs as an octopus step `kubectl apply -f modelservicedeploy.yml`
But I am getting the following error,

```
Calamari.exe : ObjectNotFound: The term 'kubectl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

The `kubectl` is installed and I've added it to the environment variable PATH, also I've tried to execute it from the location but still didn't work

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Could the path be missing for the user that the Tentacle (for a worker) or Octopus Server (for run on Server) is running under? Try adding `OctopusPrintVariables` with `true` to the variables for the project, that will print the $env:Path out to the log.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error with with different tool:

```
Calamari.exe : ObjectNotFound: The term 'XXX' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

The issue turned out to be this bug: https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/5755

The combination of `Windows Server 2019` + `.net framework 4.7.2` caused the script to exit with the above error when writing any output to `stdout`.

The solution was to install the `.Net framework 4.8`.